# React Material UI Responsive Appbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a react project which has top appbar with responsive drawer on left side. This appbar is responsive with FormControl items in it. On open the left nav drawer pushes the content to fit responsive and in the top appbar, FormControl wraps down, changing height of the top appbar. Am able to capture this change in height for all items in the side nav, except for the menu button on top left and IconButton inside of it.

I want to capture the accurate aapbar height to push the content below of it, which is not happening for click on Menu and inside IconButton button.

I used react ref for this, still does not give me accurate dimensions.

Attaching working example:

https://xzbot.csb.app/

If you reduce the window and click on menu button, as the drawer expands, second languages item wraps down and increases the height of appbar.

Any suggestions how can I get proper height of the top appbar much appreciated.

Thanks,
Gautam

Comment: You could add code of what you have tried

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy - Included code example in the description